# Session variables changing on refresh/button click

Tags: php, session-variables

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
$_SESSION['catRandNum'] = rand(0,2);
```

That is one of my variables randomly selecting a category for my hangman mini-game I am making. [image: Before Refresh]

[image: After Refresh]

Is there any way I could make the variable stay constant so the category will stay the same? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you don't want to change it, don't reassign it.

Comment: Check if session variable already exists. If not, generate a new one, if it does, do nothing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this is what you want:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['catRandNum'])) {
    $_SESSION['catRandNum'] = rand(0,2);
}
```

If this is a new session, the variable is set randomly. Otherwise it keeps its value.